# Causality of unit step response

Tags: discrete-mathematics, signal-processing

Let's say I have the given unit step response function $s$ defined as:
$$s[n] = x[n]*a^{|n|} \text{ where } x[n] = u[n]$$ In this equation, I assumed that this system was causal since there was no dependence on future inputs. However, it is actually not causal for the following reason:

> Since $h[n] \neq 0$ for $n < 0$, the system is not causal.

I don't understand the logic behind this. Mathematically, I can't see how this makes sense. Because, $x[n]$ only depends on the current value of $n$. Can someone reconcile this?

Comment: But $s$ depends on past and future values of $x$.

Comment: But, if $n \geq 0$, then $s[n]$ is just $a^n$ and if $n < 0$, then $s[n] = 0$. So how exactly does it depend on past and future values?

Comment: $*$ denotes a convolution operation.